# Очередная проблема с кодировкой MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysqli, mysql-workbench

Очередная проблема с кодировкой, в таблице русские символы отображаются некорректно.

У меня есть программа которая вставляет данные в базу Mysql интервально. В mysql.log вижу вот такой запрос:

```
181207 12:48:25    62 Query     INSERT INTO tSplitSkillStatus (acd, skill, timestamp, skillname, callswaiting, oldestcallwaiting, expectedwaittime, listxml) VALUES (1, '10', 1544176105, 'Прямые звонки', 0, 0, -1, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><listxml><list><agentname>СЦ Кашири</agentname><agentid>1247</agentid><auxreason>*лия</auxreason><state>*    ис</state>
```

Синтаксис SQL некорректный, обратите внимание на русские символы, т.е. при вставке данных русские символы отображаются правильно.

Далее, файл настроек my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
init-connect="SET NAMES utf8"
skip-character-set-client-handshake

[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
```

При подключении программы, которая вставляет данные в ДБ, в логе вижу такие записи:

```
62 Connect   tcpgate@localhost on clintrtdb
62 Query     SET NAMES utf8
62 Query     SET NAMES latin1
62 Query     SET character_set_results = NULL
62 Query     SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL = 0
```

хотелось бы понять, в итоге какая кодировка используется при вставке данных?
На выходе вижу:
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я неправильно указал параметры переопределения кодировки клиента, просьба подсказать правильные варианты.

Comment: Похоже кодировку latin выставляет ваша программа. Судя по строчкам `SET NAMES utf8; SET NAMES latin1` первый раз правильная кодировка ставится параметрами клиента, второй раз программой. Что за программа? Если это фреймворк, то посмотрите документацию на предмет настроек кодировки в конфиге

Comment: Нет это не фреймворк, программа на C++, настроек кодировки я не нашел в ней. Может быть как-то можно игнорировать на стороне сервера эту кодировку?

Comment: смущает прямое указание `SET NAMES latin1`. Идет оно явно из программы. программа случайно не через ODBC коннектится?

Comment: Да, через ODBC, разработчики посоветовали мне проверить MySQL Unicode драйвер.